# Tunneling SFTP to another computer

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ssh

Run OpenSuse 13.1 and I have access to a server via SFTP:

Question: Can a friend tunnel from another computer to mine so that he can use my SFTP client on my machine? Is this possible?

In other words: We  have a situation where I have a SSH/SFTP access from my workstation to a server.
Now a friend—living somewhere else should use this access, which only works from my machine. Note the server is not (!!) directly accessible from his workstation.

We need to have SSH access from his computer to mine so that he can then SSH to the server in question.

How can I accomplish this? Why can we not just SSH from #1 to console on #2 then SSH from machine #2 to console 3 within the session? This is called “leapfrogging”

Answer (score 6):

if your friend can ssh to you he you can tunnel like so:

`ssh -L 8022:<sftp-server-ip>:22 <your-workstation-ip>`

With this ssh session active your friend could access the server with `localhost:8022`
The catch is the they need to be able to ssh to your workstation which you'll need to forward a port on your router to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by first connecting to your server via SSH, creating a remotely accessible tunnel for your friend. For example:

```
ssh -g -L 10022:127.0.0.1:22 [your-server's-ip-address]
```

The -g switch is what makes the tunnel available to remote hosts. Assuming port 10022 is open on your workstation, he could then use the following command to connect to the server:

```
ssh [your-workstation's-ip-address] -p 10022
```

Be aware that connecting like this will obfuscate the origin of this connection. Also, anyone who knows about this tunnel will be able to use it, unless your local firewall restricts access to port 10022 (in this example).